# Generate random coordinates in a rectangle qt

Tags: c++, qt, random

I have a rectangle with length 27.5 and width 3.5 and I am supposed to generate coordinates within this rectangle which are unique i.e., without any duplicates. The number of coordinates that need to be generated are based on the size of a list. Here is what I have done so far using Qt:

```
struct coordinates_t{
    int x;
    int y;    
};

QVector<coordinates_t> coordinatesList;
QList<QString> listOfDevices;
//populate listOfDevices

for( int i = 0; i < listOfDevices.count(); i++)
{
coordinatesList.pushback({rand() % 51 + (-25), rand() % 11 + (-5)});
}
```

The problem now is that even though the rand function generates random numbers within the rectangle, it does not however avoid duplicates. Is there someway in which I can avoid the duplicates and produce unique coordinates within the given rectangle.

Comment: See [`QVector::contains`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#contains).

Comment: Just check that there isn't already the same tuple in `coodinatesList` before you `pushback` the newly generated one (tip: start overloading `==` operator for `coordinates_t`)

Comment: If the dimensions are 27.5x3.5, why are the coordinates `int`s, then, which must be whole numbers? And why is the sample code generating X coordinates between -25 to 26, and -5 to 6? This does not make any sense.

Comment: You don't specify the desired distribution of points. A simple way would be to distribute the N points on a grid within the rectangle (the aspect ratio is approximately 8:1 so you use 8 times as many gridlines on the long axis as on the short. If you need them to look less "gridlike" then pick two random values for each point, and shift the point by those values (in x then y), being sure to keep the shifts smaller that the grid spacing.

Comment: If you need unique entries, also have a look at `QMap`, maybe `QMap<QPoint>`. There you could just `insert` `QPoint`s and check for `QMap`'s `size()` to know when you are finished. And just some general hints: In Qt applications, prefer `qrand()` and if you want the random numbers to be different each time you run the application, seed the number generator with `qsrand([...])`.

Comment: Could you probably provide an example @Bugfinger

Comment: @smyslov: That would have to wait till tomorow. But I will try to put something together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that demonstrates the check for duplicates using `QVector` and `QPoint`. If you want to use [`QVector::contains`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#contains) with your own struct, you must implement the `operator==()`.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QVector>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QDateTime>    
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QVector<QPoint> point_vector;
    qsrand(QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch());

    const int max_points = 20;

    while(point_vector.size() < max_points)
    {
        QPoint point(qrand() % 27, qrand() % 4);
        if(!point_vector.contains(point))
            point_vector.append(point);
    }

    qDebug() << point_vector;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The normal way of solving this would be to shuffle a predefined set of coordinates. But this isn't practical in this instance. Furthermore, duplicates on one axis are allowed too.

Consider solving this by

1. Defining `bool operator<(const coordinates_t& other) const` and `bool operator==(const coordinates_t& other) const`
2. Use a `std::set<coordinates_t>`. This is possible once you've done (1).
3. Insert random coordinates into the `set` *until* the desired size of the set is reached.
4. Copy that set into the `QVector` if you still need them to be stored that way. If you want to preserve the insertion order (`set` will sort the values according to how you define the operators in (1)), then retain the `QVector`, and only push a point to it if insertion into the `set` was successful.

Insertion of a duplicate into a `set` is an O(Log N) no-op. Also note that `rand()` as a linear congruential generator *might* throw out undesirable autocorrelation effects that manifest themselves particularly in an x, y plot. Consider using Mersenne Twister instead.

Comment: Using  a QVector is not really a necessity. However, could you probably provide an example @Bathsheba

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness sake. :)

In my comment I suggested using a **QMap** but I had a **std::set** in mind, which in Qt does not have an equivalent. :(

Anyway, I wanted to see if a **QMap** could do the trick as well and came up with an ... a little bit strange approach.

Putting a **QPoint** into the **QMap** does not work since the inserted **key** needs to have the `<` operator implemented, which is not the case for **QPoint** but it for **QPair**. Thus my choice.

The idea is to (a bit like in *thuga*'s answer) compare the `size()` of the resulting list to the list of devices and insert until they are equally long. However, since I bound myself to using **QMap**, here's my version. :)

```
#include <ctime>
#include <QMap>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPair>

int main()
{
    qsrand(std::time(nullptr));

    QMap<QPair<int, int>, QString> coords;

    QList<QString> listOfDevices;
    //populate listOfDevices
    for (int i = 10; i < 30; ++i) {
        listOfDevices.append("dev" + QString::number(i));
    }

    qDebug() << "Number of devices:" << listOfDevices.size();

    int demo_counter = 0;
    while (coords.size() < listOfDevices.size()) {
        coords.insert(
                qMakePair(qrand() % 51 + (-25), qrand() % 11 + (-5)),
                listOfDevices.at(coords.size())
                );
        ++demo_counter;
    }

    for (auto it = coords.cbegin(); it != coords.cend(); ++it) {
        qDebug() << it.key() << ':' << it.value();
    }
    qDebug() << "Entries inserted:" << coords.size();
    qDebug() << "Tries needed:" << demo_counter;

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs (see how it tried **23** times for adding **20** entries):

```
Number of devices: 20
QPair(-25,-2) : "dev14"
QPair(-23,3) : "dev28"
QPair(-22,5) : "dev20"
QPair(-20,5) : "dev11"
QPair(-19,-1) : "dev22"
QPair(-19,0) : "dev27"
QPair(0,-2) : "dev29"
QPair(5,-3) : "dev23"
QPair(9,0) : "dev28"
QPair(10,1) : "dev17"
QPair(11,-5) : "dev18"
QPair(11,4) : "dev25"
QPair(16,-2) : "dev12"
QPair(16,4) : "dev26"
QPair(21,-2) : "dev26"
QPair(21,2) : "dev16"
QPair(21,4) : "dev15"
QPair(23,-2) : "dev24"
QPair(25,2) : "dev21"
QPair(25,4) : "dev23"
Entries inserted: 20
Tries needed: 23
```

Since your requirement is not exactly clear and you might be able to fill in the **devices** within the `while` loop as well, there is no way to tell, which solution is better suited but if you really want two different lists, one with **devices** and one with **coords**, the solution with the `contains()` check is to be preferred.

Comment: The problem with your solution, is that `QMap::insert` replaces the old value if there is a duplicate. Therefore you end up with the same device occupying multiple coordinates. You would have to use `QMap::contains` to check if the key (`QPair<int, int>` in this case) already exists in the map.

Comment: @thuga: Hmm, after the loop, every device has been assigned to one coordinate. In case of a duplicate the "older" one is overwritten. But yes, Qt is weird in this regard. the `std::set` I had in mind initially just does not insert any newer duplicate value. Or do I misunderstand your "occupying multiple coordinates"?

Comment: That is what I mean. If you look at your output, you can see for example `dev26` is in the `QPair(16,4)` coordinate, and in the `QPair(21,-2)` coordinate, i.e. it's occupying multiple coordinates, while for example `dev13` is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Oh my ... you are right. If there's a duplicate coordinate, the device that was initially assigned to it, is overridden and then since the new device assignment does not increase the `size()` of `coords`, the same device gets assigned again to another pair of coordinates. Thanks for pointing that out.